# Full-proof way to launch a webpage

Tags: windows, google-chrome, uac

On my machine (Windows 10), I have one Administrative user and one standard user.

I launch chrome on my Administrative user account. I then lock my account and log into my standard user account. I then run cmd as Administrator and am prompted with UAC. When I launch chrome (start chrome) nothing happens. I have attached a stack trace below from --enable-logging --v=1. I am still able to launch chrome when I run the cmd without elevated privileges as the standard user.

```
[1044:4904:0723/141901.799:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[1044:4904:0723/141901.799:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[1044:10988:0723/141901.800:ERROR:process_singleton_win.cc(411)] Lock file can not be created! Error code: 32
[1044:10988:0723/141901.800:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1292)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

From a high level I need a full-proof way to launch a webpage. Obviously users use many browsers so a chrome-only solution is not viable. I am launching my webpage from cmd using start https://www.stackoverflow.com/. It is my understanding the default browser is used (which in my reproducible example is chrome)

A real world use case is the standard user installs some software. The software installer uses UAC to run with administrator privilege so the installer is now running under the Administrative user account. The installer launches a webpage that details information about the software. The webpage actually doesn't launch because the Administrative user left chrome open on their Windows account. So this is an edge case that is not even applicable to most machines with a single Windows account.

Comment: Do the 2 users have different Chrome profiles?

Comment: @DavidPostill - Chrome user profiles are stored within `%LocalAppData%`

Comment: @Ramhound It looks like he's running both instance as Admin - so same profile - and it's already running in the other locked login.

Comment: There is nothing fool-proof about running a browser with Administrator rights.

Comment: I don't need my browser to run with administrator rights. I just need the browser to run.

Comment: Can I ask why it is necessary to launch the website as administrator?, also In most use cases I wouldn't suggest allowing any user to run a browser with admin privileges?. I think there is more to the scenario you have described?

Comment: Please see my real world use case (last paragraph). The installer launches the website so the website is running as administrator because the installer was. I agree its totally unnecessary for the website to run as administrator but many installers need elevated UAC because they write to restricted directories etc. My issue is its absolutely critical the website launches because the website goes over how to use the software.

Comment: “The webpage actually doesn't launch because the Administrative user left chrome open on their Windows account.” - With the real world example, it sounds like your question belongs on Stack Overflow, still not clear how your launching a browser with an installer as a different user (most definitely not normal behavior)

Comment: The question was posted on stack overflow but closed and recommended I post here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
args = ["start", "/wait", url, "&", "exit", "/b", "%errorlevel"]
completed = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print("exit status", completed.returncode)
```

Comment: returncode != 0 indicates something went wrong launching the webpage.